# Calculate the average for user's input

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to calculate the average for the user's input but I am not sure how to add up the grades since its a while loop and the user can keep entering grades. I also don't want to count the zero to exit the loop as part of the average.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
    {
        int grade = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        
        
        System.out.print("Enter grade or zero to quit(1-100):");
        grade= input.nextInt();
        
               
        while(grade>0)
        { 
            if (grade >= 90)
            System.out.println("A");
            

            else if (grade >= 80)
                    
            System.out.println("B");
            

            else if (grade >= 70)
            System.out.println("C");
            

            else if (grade >= 60)
            System.out.println("D");

            else
                {System.out.println("F");
                    }
            counter+=1;
                    
            System.out.print("Enter grade or zero to quit(1-100):");
            grade=input.nextInt();
            
           
        }
```

[ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYMnc.png)

I want to print one more line saying "The average of these (number of grades) Grades is(average)"

Comment: Keep a running total. If you don't want to count the zero . . . don't count it.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a sum of all the grades, and divide by the count.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
    int grade = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    
    while(grade>0) { 
    
        System.out.print("Enter grade or zero to quit(1-100):");
        grade= input.nextInt();
        sum += grade;
        counter++;
        float average = sum / counter;
        
        if (grade >= 90) {
            System.out.println("A");
        }
        else if (grade >= 80) {
            System.out.println("B");
        }
        else if (grade >= 70) {
            System.out.println("C");
        }
        else if (grade >= 60) {
            System.out.println("D");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("F");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
    int grade = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    float average=0;
    do{
    System.out.print("Enter grade or zero to quit(1-100):");
        grade= input.nextInt();
        sum += grade;
        counter++;
       average = sum / counter;
        
        if (grade >= 90) {
            System.out.println("A");
        }
        else if (grade >= 80) {
            System.out.println("B");
        }
        else if (grade >= 70) {
            System.out.println("C");
        }
        else if (grade >= 60) {
            System.out.println("D");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("F");
        }
    }while( grade > 0 );
    
        System.out.println(average);
    }
```

Comment: do-while solution

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int grade = 0;
    int counter = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    float average = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter grade or zero to quit(1-100):");
    grade = input.nextInt();
    if (grade > 0) {
        counter = 1;
        while (grade > 0) {
            System.out.print("Enter grade or zero to quit(1-100):");
            grade = input.nextInt();
            sum += grade;
            counter++;
            average = sum / counter;

            if (grade >= 90) {
                System.out.println("A");
            } else if (grade >= 80) {
                System.out.println("B");
            } else if (grade >= 70) {
                System.out.println("C");
            } else if (grade >= 60) {
                System.out.println("D");
            } else {
                System.out.println("F");
            }
        }
    } 
    System.out.println(average);
}
```

Comment: solution with while